# How to use Jquery for populate list from database.?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Here is my code. I got it from jquery tutorial page and its works well.now i need to load my list items from table data

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
#sortable1,#sortable2,#sortable3 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 143px;
}

#sortable1 li,#sortable2 li,#sortable3 li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
            connectWith : "ul"
        });
        $("ul.dropfalse").sortable({
            connectWith : "ul",
            dropOnEmpty : false
        });
        $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Available Medicines</div>
    <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Panadol</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Ciprofloaxin</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Piriton</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Zitricin</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Brufen</li>
    </ul>

    <div style="font-weight: bold;">Selected Medicines</div>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">
    </ul>
    <br style="clear: both">
</body>
```

Please help me to sortout this issue. 
thanks

Comment: just need how to populate list from jquery (with Gson also prefer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could make JQuery AJAX call to get Table data, In the success callback function you would populate the list.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data)
    {
       var rowData= data.split(",");
       $.each( rowData, function( index, value ){
$("#sortable1 ul li:last").append('<li class="ui-state-default">'+value +'</li>');
       });      
    }
});
```

Java method should return the comma separated table data.

Comment: thanks dear Tech Mahesh :-) I'll try in this way & let u know

Comment: then how to save those selected list.?

Comment: Do you want to save into DB? If so again use AJAX call or form submit action.